# Does it make any sense to use `baseline` value with `justify-content`, `justify-items` or `justify-self` in CSS Flex/Grid?

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment, css-grid

MDN [`align-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content), [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) and [`justify-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items) describe `baseline` as one of their possible values. While `baseline` makes sense when is used with `align-items` or `align-self`, I don't get how it could work along with `justify-content`, `justify-items`, `justify-self` and `align-content` properties. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MDN is not accurate here as there is no baseline for `justify-content`

If you check [the actual Flexbox specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-justify-content) you will see that there is no `baseline` value for `justify-content`

```
Value:  flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around
```

In the near future and as defined in the [CSS Box Alignment Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/) we will have more generic way to align elements and even there `baseline` is a not a valid value of `justify-content`

```
Value:  normal | <content-distribution> | <overflow-position>? [ <content-position> | left | right ]

<content-distribution> = space-between | space-around | space-evenly | stretch

<overflow-position> = unsafe | safe

<content-position> = center | start | end | flex-start | flex-end
```

---

By the way, there is `baseline` for `justify-items` in the new specificiation: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#propdef-justify-items but this property doesn't exist in the actual Flexbox specification (same for `justify-self`)

Related: [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/8620333)

`align-content` doesn't accept `baseline` with Flexbox (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property) but it does in [the New Specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#propdef-align-content)

---

The same apply for CSS grid but you can find `justify-items` and `justify-self` there: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#row-align

Actually I don't have a clear example to illustrate the `baseline` with those properties but I am pretty sure in most of the case it will consider a fallback value as defined in the Spec: